# Unable to set width to table headers while using fixed table header in reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

I have a table with headers but I am unable to change the width of headings. I want to make table with fixed header.
But my fixed header class column headings and data is getting misaligned.

How to get this working?

### JSX code

```
 <div className="table-responsive">
      <table className="table-hover fixed_header">
         <thead>
            <tr>
              {this.props.columns.map(col=>{
                return <th key={col} >{col}</th>
              })}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.props.data.map((item,index)=>(
              <tr key={item+index} >
                {item.map((i,index1)=>{
                  return <td key={index1+"+"+i}>{i}</td>
                })}
              </tr>)            
              )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

### CSS

```
.fixed_header tbody{
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    height:80vh;
    width:100%;
  }
  .fixed_header thead tr{
    display:block;
  }

  .fixed_header th, .fixed_header td{
      box-sizing: content-box;
      width: 30%;
  }
```

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot what you mean by "misaligned"? I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please add more details.

Comment: Header1 header2 header3 header4 header5 header6
Data1 Data of header2------big data of header3  data4 data5 data6